# Facebook Graph API Change: Picture type (size) no longer working?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to Facebook's Graph API documentation ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)), you can access various sizes of a user's profile picture through URLs such as:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)/picture?type=small
https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)/picture?type=large
```

You'll notice that the first resolves to a url ending in _t.jpg (the small thumbnail) and the second ending in _n.jpg (the large image).  So far so good.  Equivalently, we should be able to query for these images like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)?fields=picture&type=small
https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)?fields=picture&type=large
```

This latter format worked as expected for many months, until just a few days ago when it suddenly started ignoring the "type" parameter entirely - everything now resolves to an image ending in _q.jpg, which is the default if no "type" is specified.  As a result, I can no longer figure out a way to query for the large image in PHP (my *real* problem).  It used to work like this:

```
$pic = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'picture', 'type' => 'large'));
```

...but as described above, "type" has spontaneously started being ignored.  I've spent several hours scouring their documentation but haven't been able to find any reference to what has changed, or the "new" way this should be done - any pointers would be hugely appreciated...

**EDIT:**

None of the following work, either (returns nothing):

```
$pic = $facebook->api('/me/picture', array('type' => 'large'));
$pic = $facebook->api('/(my_uid)/picture', array('type' => 'large'));
$pic = $facebook->api('/me/picture/?type=large');
$pic = $facebook->api('/(my_uid)/picture/?type=large');
```

Basically, since Facebook broke things a few days ago there doesn't seem to be any way to get a non-default picture size from PHP.  You can try out some of the calls yourself from the Graph API Explorer ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)).

Other related/relevant links:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978761/facebook-graph-api-will-not-give-me-picture-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718704/requesting-picture-for-event
```

Comment: Unless it's a sporadic problem not affecting all users/objects, it seems to be working fine for me now. Maybe it's fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround - profile pictures of various sizes can still be accessed via an FQL query:

```
$pic = $facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query', 'query'=>"SELECT pic_big FROM user WHERE uid=$fb_uid"));
```

("pic_big" is equivalent to "type=large" - see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)).

This still doesn't explain why the GRAPH call suddenly broke though, or why image sizes don't seem to be accessible via Graph at all anymore (which I'd still like to know)...but at least there's *some* way to get the other size photos.

Gotta love Facebook and their top-notch reliability...

Comment: Do you have an idea to do the same for post-attached pictures?

Answer (score 19):

You must request the API with the [field_expansion syntax](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)

These api requests works :

`$results = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'picture.height(300).width(300)'));`

`$results = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'picture.type(large)'));`

Comment: I tried this but on a picture object - and I got the error:
Uncaught OAuthException: Subfields are not supported by picture

Answer (score 4):

As described in [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129804577163441) on Facebook, you can request this via the new API "[field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)" syntax.

This works for me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/____OBJECT_ID____?fields=picture.type(large)
```

Comment: I really despise how Facebook just changes/breaks things "by design" without bothering to mention it on their docs. Anyway, thanks for the tip - looks like both workarounds work :)

Comment: Seems to always return the exact same image, no matter if you type large, medium, small etc.. I can get a list of items, however the widths/heights aren't unique enough to pull them through accurately (they seem to change per image)