# Getting Facebook picture in large format

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to extract a picture from a post on my page, but I only seem to get it in a small/normal size, and I need it to be large.

I've tried:

```
$facebook->api('/' . FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID . '/feed?fields=picture,type,link');
```

And:

```
$facebook->api('/' . PICTURE_OBJECT_ID . '/?type=large');
```

But these both return this, even though it exists much larger:
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10425079_783550735069408_4518815346697887155_n.jpg?oh=c72ed199f78f7627b6b78f8eb0da8108&oe=55735F64

How do I get it out as a large picture?

Answer (score 1):

Sure that there is a better way to do this, but this one works at the moment.

Get the URL part between the two "_", that is the Facebook ID. In your example "783550735069408".

Now build a new URL like this:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" + FacebookID + "/picture?width=320&height=320"
```

In this example you get a 320x320 image, if you what anyelse size you must to change the width and height params.

I wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post

[Facebook Graph API Change: Picture type (size) no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982276/facebook-graph-api-change-picture-type-size-no-longer-working)

but it actually looks like taht this is the regular size of this image.

Comment: They only seem to work with the /me object, but I always get 135x135 no matter what I do, when looking up the picture in a certain post.